# Web socket connection can't be established

Tags: html, websocket

I am able to establish connection between browser and server lately.. But for the past two days the connection is not getting established.. I am unable to figure out what could have gone wrong?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function WebSocketTest()
{
 if ("WebSocket" in window)
 {
   var x=document.getElementById('chat').value;
   // Let us open a web socket
   var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7869/echo");
   ws.onopen = function()
   {
    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
    ws.send(x);
    var send=document.getElementById('fill');
    send.innerHTML = send.innerHTML+'<br>'+ x;
   };
   ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
   { 
    var received_msg = evt.data;
    var send=document.getElementById('fill');
    send.innerHTML = send.innerHTML +'<br>'+ received_msg;
   };
   ws.onclose = function()
   { 
    // websocket is closed.
    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
   };
  }
  else
  {
    // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
   alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sse">
 <input type="text" id="chat"></div><br>
 <button type='submit' onclick='javascript:WebSocketTest()'>Send</button>
<div id='fill'>hi</div>

</body>
```

Here is the code and websocket server is listening the 7869 port.

Comment: Does `onopen` accures? Add an `onerror` event to get if any error happens. Can you check if the server gets your message or not?

Comment: i got a basic websocket server written in perl. It is not opening port 7869 as tcp socket programming.

Comment: Try to use standart port 80 - if this would work then there is a problem with port 7869. Try to turn off the antivirus to see if it is blocking your connection. Did it help?

Comment: I am using xampp's apache in port 80. Do HAProxy help to detect websocket signal from normal http requests.?